# File permissions changed during sftp in paramiko python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sftp, paramiko

I am copying a dir and its content recursively from remote to local.
but i found 755 permission on files has been changed to 644 on local after copy.

```
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(hostname, username=uname, password='password')
    sftp = client.open_sftp()
    def copyremotedir(src,dest,sftp):   
        if not os.path.isdir(dest):
            os.makedirs(dest)

        for item in sftp.listdir_attr(src):

            item_name = str(item.filename)
            if stat.S_ISDIR(item.st_mode):
                copyremotedir(src + "/" + item_name, dest + "/" + item_name, sftp)
            else:
                sftp.get(src + "/" + item_name, dest + "/" + item_name)
```

Answer (score 3):

`scp` / `sftp` copy file *content* - they don't deal with file metadata, such as ownership or permissions.

If you want to preserve those, you'll need to use `rsync` or create a `tar` archive.

Comment: I need to do all these in a python automation script, which behaves wierd, wandering why.

Comment: Nowhere in the snippet you enclosed, @Bibek, do you _actually set_ the mode of the file you create.
E.g., use `chmod(path, mode)` as in [link](http://tinyurl.com/qxjzqxt).